# Add Unique Random Points to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, unique, point

I'm trying to program Minesweeper in Java. I am currently trying to create an x amount of unique Mines, which positions ( as POINTS, where x corresponds to Row and y to column for JavaFX) are saved in a one dimensional Array. So that I can then return the list to the controller.

I could start and:

- create all Points, add them to the array, test every Point with every other Point, overwrite the doubles with new Points, test again...
  but that seems awfully inelegant.

My problem so far was, that when I test whether or not my just created point is .equal() to every Point in the Mines[] array, it throws an exception since the array is empty.

This new solution is the best I came up with so far, but still buggy. Either some pointers with the current code or a more elegant approach would be great!

Thanks for the help

```
MineNumber = mines;
Mheight = height;
Mwidth = width;
int row;
int column;
int counter = 0;
Point[] Mines = new Point[MineNumber]; //5
Random Rnd = new Random(); 
boolean create=true;
```

no clue why it only works with -1 there, but after some trying this way it at least runs

```
do {
             if (counter < MineNumber - 1) {   
            row = Rnd.nextInt(Mwidth);
            column = Rnd.nextInt(Mheight);
            Point p = new Point(row, column);
            System.out.println(p); //test

              if (counter <= 0) {
                Mines[0] = p;
                counter++;
              } else {
                for (int i = 0;i < counter; i++) {
                    if (Mines[i].equals(p)) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        Mines[counter] = p;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
             }
        } else {
            create = false;
        }
    } while (create);
    System.out.println(Mines[0] + " " + Mines[1] + " " + Mines[2] + " "
            + Mines[3] + " " + Mines[4]);

}

Output:
java.awt.Point[x=3,y=2]
java.awt.Point[x=1,y=8]
java.awt.Point[x=9,y=12]

java.awt.Point[x=3,y=2] java.awt.Point[x=1,y=8] java.awt.Point[x=9,y=12] java.awt.Point[x=9,y=12] null
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having?

Comment: If you could initialize the entire array to all equal zero, would that fix your initial Problem?

Comment: My solution doesnt do what I want, since Mines[3] is the same as Mine[3] and Mine[4] is empty. When the Minenumber is 5 and also I am wondering if there are more elegant solutions to this.

Comment: If possible, please shorten your question down to just the specific question you need answered.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will do so in the future. I guess that would work although I´d have to replace the first (0,0) with my first generated Point. Wouldn´t that give problems if I actually generated (0,0) on any go?

Answer (score 1):

Store each location of a placed mine in a set:

```
Set<Point> placedMines = new HashSet<>();
```

Then you can do your loop from 0 till mine number without the need to change the index and running into issues with accessing an element that was not yet set.

You can check easily:

```
Point p =  Point(row, column);
while (placedMines.contains(p)) {
  // there is already a mine at that location, select a different one.
  p =  Point(Rnd.nextInt(Mwidth), Rnd.nextInt(Mheight));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I just have a second Array, where I check for unique values. If its not in the 2nd array I´ll add it do both?

Comment: You have your array `Point[] Mines` and a `Set` `Set<Point> placedMines`. You might even consider instead of using an array and a Set, simply putting the `Point`s representing the location of a mine in a `List`. The lookup for the list is the same as for a Set.